# Passport.js failing to both update database and/or generate error

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I’m implementing a local-signup strategy using passport.js, and have been having some issues with getting the basic proof of concept up and running. My goal for this precise moment is to be able to sign up new users if the email address they’re adding is not present in the database (db is initialized and empty right now) and have a success JSON message propagate to their screen when successful, and receive an error when the email address has already been entered in the database, with a corresponding JSON failure message.

The error I’m receiving is that when I hit the submit button with both email address and password filled out, the loading stalls and I receive the following on my cmd:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `createdAt`,
`updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User` LIMIT 1;
```

Which I presume is coming from the console.log(info) statement from app.js, yet no insertions are being made to the empty table in the database on new usernames, nor is the error for non-distinct emails being triggered.

I have a few hypotheses for why this might be occurring:

1)  There is an issue with the way that the database is being queried to determine whether or not a user is in the table. (I’ve done various permutations to emulate the ./config/passport.js strategy defined halfway down [this link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local), but the problem persists)

2)  The signup.ejs attributes need to be changed and/or these values need to be modified in a different way before being passed into LocalStrategy as an object. (Similar to 1, I’ve spent a fair amount of time tinkering with the attribute fields to try to get them to conform to Chris Sevilleja’s implementation in the above link as well as the official passport.js docs, but haven’t found anything meaningful in terms of expected out.)

### App.js

[image]

### Passport.js

[image]

### signup.ejs

[image]

### sequelize.js

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your queries to DB are incorrect.
Sequelize using promises
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/getting-started/#promises

```
db.User.findOne({where: {email: email}})
.then(function(user){
   //do smth with user
})
.catch(function(error){
   //handle error
})
```